# Unity project no longer opening after establishing Git repository

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, crash

I spent a few hours working on a new project, I intend to work on this one with a friend, so I thought I would set up a git repository so we can effectively work together. After doing this, the engine crashes leaving the message "Unity is already in list. You cannot locate the same version" for a brief second before flashing to white. It will not open the editor at all.

The steps taken to establish the repository were as follows:
 1) make sure settings are the way they need to be in unity
 1.5) close unity
 2) create new gitlab project
 3) git init, add *, commit, remote add origin [project clone ssh], and push -u origin master
 4) remove library folder and push again.
 5) created a .gitignore file to ignore library and temp going forward

[Edit: Windows OS, Unity v2020.1.0a14, unity hub is up to date]

Comment: When asking this please add **all required information** for reproducing the issue ... which Unity version? Which OS? how exactly looks your `.gitignore` like? Latest should be **at least** including all [these exceptions](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore). Also probably late but ... before using any external tool always make backups of your project ... you never know what will happen ;)

Comment: Chances are things like temp, library, logs, obj are read only...... my suggestion.  ditch the git repository for now, reset all the files to read/write, check it now opens in unity, then create the git repository but ensure you use the known required exceptions

Comment: Maybe there are some hints in Unity's Editor.log. Look at ~/Library/Logs/Unity (macOS) or %USER%/LocalLow/Unity (Windows)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an authentication issue and I have a partial solution. Please see [my response on the Unity Forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-is-already-in-list-you-cannot-locate-the-same-version.785405/#post-5649724). If you were doing anything with network adapters (turning them on or off or switching between two) chances are Unity's authentication wants to use the one that isn't available anymore. I had this message present when trying to load up a project after I had previously turned my wireless adapter on and connected to a network during the previous Unity session and then later turned it off after I had exited Unity.

In that it's a partial solution, currently I cannot open these Unity projects without having my wireless adapter enabled. I'm not connected to a network with it, but Hub nor Unity Editor will allow me to open a project unless the adapter is on.

Answer (score 0):

Unity 2020 is in preview, likely when your buddy worked on your project he was not working in 2020 and things got corrupt somehow by switching versions back and forth. Try downgrading to the latest stable version 2019.3 and it should fix your problem.